# 130V DC Motor Control

Tags: arduino, pwm, dc-motor, control

I am interested in building a control circuit for a motor.

More specifically this [motor](https://www.bodine-electric.com/Asp/ProductModel.asp?Context=13&Name=24A-D+Series+Parallel+Shaft+DC+Gearmotor&Model=0186).

The model I want to control is the 130V model, 0.48A, which should make it at ~62W for the motor, and 1/17 HP.

Any ideas on how to manage to control this?

I want to use the Arduino as a PID controller, the feedback will be supplied through a passive 2 wire hall-effect sensor.

So I want to be able to use a PWM port, or if necessary I can use multiple digital ports.

Any ideas how to build this controller ?

Initial schematic for the controller.

[schematic http://files.matoski.com/misc/dcmotorschemcontrol.jpg](http://files.matoski.com/misc/dcmotorschemcontrol.jpg)

Components in the schematic

- H11D3M
- IRF520PBF
- IXTH20P50P

Comment: Peak current at start up and stall should be factored into the design - these currents could easily be 3 amps. The controller - what are you trying to control on the motor with hall-effect sensors - can you explain?

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Comment: Perhaps an [H-Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge).

Comment: Search electronics.stackexchange.com for "[dc-motor] [arduino]"
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-motor+arduino

Also be sure to search for "[dc-motor] [pwm]" and "[dc-motor] [h-bridge]" as these are commonly used DC motor driving schemes.

Comment: @PhilFrost, Of course I have done research for this, I'm asking here for help.

Comment: I've attached the schematic to my initial design, but I was hoping first that you will help me see if I'm on the right track.

Comment: @Andyaka,the purpose of the motor is to spin some ladles that are submersed in water. The hall-effect sensor just gives me the rpm of the motor, and I use this with a PID controller to control the speed at a desired rate lets say around ~120RPM

Comment: @sherrellbc yeah my initial design is to use an H-bridge, but I've never worked with 24V+ for motors. There are a lot of motor drivers available for up to 40V, but I haven't seen any for 40V+

Comment: @ilijamt so, give us a place to start. Is the question, "how do I built an H-bridge for 130V?"

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'll comment that using a passive Hall-effect sensor to generate a PID controller is not remotely in the works, and it's not even an appropriate concern. What you will be creating is a velocity loop, not a PID.

Comment: Links to the datasheets for the components.

[H11D3M](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/H1/H11D3M.pdf)

[IRF520PBF](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf)

[IXTH20P50P](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/205/DS99984B(IXTH-T20P50P)-230828.pdf)

I can use [IRF620PBF](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91027/sihf620.pdf) they are rated for 200V, as for the other IXTH20P50P is rated for 500V, 20A

Comment: @PhilFrost, yeah that is my question is how to build a H-Bridge for 130V that will be safe to use

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, why are you saying it's not a PID? If we add load to the motor the speed will decrease and we will need to increase the power, so we have the PID parts, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ilijamt - What you are describing is a simple velocity loop, with feedback (P)roportional to the velocity error. If you were to generate a PID controller you would have to take both the (I)ntegral and the (D)erivative of your velocity. The derivative of a pulse train (such as your sensor produces) is not usable for this purpose. Additionally, the derivative of velocity is acceleration, and this is not terribly useful in physical terms. Please look up the definition of PID loop.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your schematic is so small that I can't tell what MOSFETs you're using, so I'll assume they are adequate.

2) Assuming your MOSFETs are properly rated for voltage and current, your high-side units are nonetheless toast. Your gate drive will apply 130 volts to the gates, and I don't know of any MOSFETs that are rated for that kind of drive.

3) While you can use the body diodes in your MOSFETs for flyback suppression, you are better off adding real diodes.

4) Those middle optocouplers are toast. Even if you activate them when all the MOSFETs are off, the stored energy in the motor, at pretty much any speed, will destroy them.

Other than that, I don't see any problems.

Comment: I've updated the schematic to a bigger picture, now you can see more clearly. 
Why do you say that the optocouplers would be toast? They are rated for 200V.

Comment: Yes, but they are not rated for .48 amps. And if they can't bleed off the current, the voltage across them will rise to some very large value - almost certainly more than 200 volts. Either way, they're toast.

Comment: And your schematic has not addressed the destruction of your high-side MOSFETs. Note that from the data sheet the absolute maximum gate-source voltage, Vgss is 30 volts. 130 volts will kill it for sure - first time, every time.

Comment: then how do you suggest I build this schematic, is it possible to get some-kind of schematic, or use a different approach to do this?

Comment: Also it's not important to move in both directions, one direction is fine

Comment: Well, the first thing is to get rid of those two middle converters. Their function appears to be to short out the motor for active breaking. Second, use a 1-watt, 12 volt zener and a 6k, 5 watt resistor to generate a 118 volt reference. Tie pin 4 of the upper optocouplers to this instead of ground. Or see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need bidirectional travel, this should work

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foI5ug.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that your original N-type MOSFET, an IRF520 would not work. If you want to know why, take a look at the data sheet. Specifically, the very first line of the Data Summary. The 1N4004 is sort of marginal for this, but I assume you won't be driving your PWM at more than a few 10s of KHz, so you should be all right. While not shown, a capacitor of a few hundred uF from the 130 volt line to ground would be a good idea, too.

Comment: I have no problem using IRF620, I can use IRF720 too just to be on the safe side. As for the diode I can always get the 1N4006 or BY500-600, just to be on the safe side. Won't the MOSFET heat up, if running for a longer period of time because I expect this will run for a couple of hours at a time, adding a heatsink to the MOSFET will help. As for the PWM, if the switch spends a total of 1 µs in transition each pulse, then at 25 kHz PWM frequency, which is 40 µs period, the transition time is 1/40 of the total. Does this look logical to you?

Comment: Also I used the optocouplers for isolation, what about now, what can I use to make the isolation better?

Comment: By all means, replace the 2N3904 with an optocoupler. According to my simulations, you don't even need a heatsink (I'm showing less than 100 mW total), but you can never be too careful. My guess about the motor inductance could be off. My concern for the diode was not voltage but speed, but, again, my sims say it's fine. Your logic is only half-way. Yes, the transition is short, but you also need to find the power during the transition. In this case, turn-on looks to be a peak of 60 watts, but only for 100 nsec. Not rectangular, so energy is ~ 1.5 uJ. Turn-off is less, ~ .5 uJ.

Comment: The motor will never be ran at full speeds, should be between 40-140 RPM, which is less than 1/3 of the spec.

Comment: When I said speed was a concern for the diode, I meant the PWM frequency and switching times.